# Indexing in custom portlet for searching

Tags: search, indexing, liferay

Which method is called for indexing portlet data and in which table is it stored?
Using search capability to a custom portlet,is it necessary to implemet reindex method with in a different class(as shown in bookmark portlet example) or can it be done within the indexer class itself?